# Marketing Cloud Barcodes

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, barcode

I've got the following code generating a barcode:

```
%%[ set @BarcodeURL = BarCodeURL(@Barcode, "Code128Auto", 100, 50)]%%

<p><img src="%%=v(@BarcodeURL)=%%"></p>
```

[image]

This works great apart from when it scan. When scanned the barcode says it has an invalid number. However, if the same barcode is manually entered it displays the amount and a valid voucher.

Is there something I'm missing in my code that would solve this issue? I noticed on the ampscript guide that I should be including a Checksum value for Code128 type barcodes but I'm not sure what this means/how to generate.

Thanks

Comment: Calculating a check digit for Code 128 barcode is complicated.  Do you have to use Code 128?  Most scanners will accommodate multiple symbologies.  Code 39 doesn't require a check digit if I recall correctly.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Scanner needs to be configured for a specific type. For some barcode types there was a configuration with and without checksum.

Comment: Thanks both. The issue was with the actual code itself not being the correct one. You dont actually need to calculate checksum for code 128 either.